# Static iframe at bottom makes webpage unscrollable

Tags: google-chrome, dom, iframe

Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/BUNVM/1/

```
<body>
    This is a test page<br/>
    (many more lines to make the page scrollable)
    This is bottom of the test page<br/>
    <iframe id="bot_frame" style="width:250px;height:240px;position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:0px;text-align:left;border:0;"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe_content = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style="background-color:#ddd">Frame content</body></html>';
    window.onload = function() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("bot_frame");
        iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
        iframe.contentWindow.document.write(iframe_content);
        iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

It has a static iframe at the bottom right corner of the screen and content is added to it by document.open() and document.write() and document.close().

Every thing is fine when you open just the output frame: http://jsfiddle.net/BUNVM/1/show/

But try to access the same output frame with a '#' at the end in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/BUNVM/1/show/#

Now attempt to scroll the page, the page is stuck at the bottom and cannot scroll up/down. Even dragging the scrollbar, hitting the arrow keys on keyboard doesnot work. However the scrolling works if you put the mouse over the iframe and then scroll with mouse wheel/pad.

I have been able to test only in Chrome v21.0.1180.89 in Ubuntu 12.04.

Please note that the above only happens when you reload the page with a hash '#' (just adding a '#' to an already loaded page doesnot reload the page).

I would like to know the reason for this and a possible solution.

Comment: Reproducible in Chromium too version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Commenting out the "iframe.contentWindow.document.close();" line solves this problem, but why should a "close()" cause the problem?

Comment: More insight: changing bottom:0px of iframe style to top:100px, we can scroll the page from the bottom upto top 100px but not above that. Also the scrolling is only possbile with click-dragging the scrollbars. Clearly the iframe document.close() is forcing the recalculation of where the parent page starts at. Appears to be a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in chrome which has been reported before: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102816

It seems that if you try to scroll while hovering over the iframe will make scrolling work again. So I created a little hack which should make it work even though it's ugly:

```
var offset = document.body.scrollTop || 0;
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(iframe_content);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

if(document.location.toString().match(/#(top)?$/)) {
    // Force a scroll on the iframe to make scrolling work again
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollTop = 0;

    // Scroll back to the original scroll position as document.close will have scrolled to the bottom
    document.body.scrollTop = offset;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tsq7N/

http://jsfiddle.net/Tsq7N/show/#

Basically I fake a scroll on the iframe which makes scrolling possible again, afterwards I set the scrollTop of the document back to what it was before the document.open/write/close happened.

Comment: I solved it by using src="javascript:function() { return "<html content>";}" in the iframe instead of doing a open, write and close.